# ILAsm syntaxes: when commands start with dot?

Tags: .net, clr, il

Some ILAsm commands/directives start with dot, some not. In particular there is a pair `'.try'` - `'catch'`. 
Is there a rule to explain/memorize when we use dots (without memorizing the complete list of all cases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From §II.15.4.1 Method body of the ECMA CLI spec:

> The method body shall contain the instructions of a program. However, it can also contain labels, additional syntactic forms and many directives that provide additional information to
>   *ilasm* and are helpful in the compilation of methods of some languages.

So, instructions are without a dot and “directives” are with a dot. I *think* that `catch` is not considered a directive on its own, because it is part of the `.catch` directive.

Comment: By this logic, `'.try {...} catch {...}'` is a one single directive that does not allow any code between these blocks.